# scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal breaks my code, but not vertical

Tags: flutter, dart

As the title implies I am having trouble changing the direction in which my cards are displayed. The code works whenever I set the scrollDirection: Axis.vertical on the ListView Widget. However, it breaks whenever I set the scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal

The error I am receiving:

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#66c25 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
> box.dart:1
> Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize'

This is the my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WorkOutPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WorkOutPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<WorkOutPage> createState() => _WorkOutPageState();
}

class _WorkOutPageState extends State<WorkOutPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Routines',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text('Create new workout routine'),
                      trailing: Icon(Icons.add),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text('Create new workout routine'),
                      trailing: Icon(Icons.add),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Card(
                child: Text('data'),
              )
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am totally new to Flutter, I've dug into the documentation without any luck. If you spot my obvious mistake, I'd love hear the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the width remains constant while the height varies.
Therefore, to align certain widgets horizontally, a height value of the parent widget is required as child widgets depend on the width or height of their parent widget.
Additionally, the ListTile widget relies on the width of its ancestor widget, therefore it must be enclosed within a SizedBox widget with a specified width.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Routines',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 60,
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: size.width - 30 * 2,
                      child: Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text('Create new workout routine'),
                          trailing: Icon(Icons.add),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: size.width - 30 * 2,
                      child: Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text('Create new workout routine'),
                          trailing: Icon(Icons.add),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Card(
                child: Text('data'),
              )
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Yupp this solved it, thank you so much for the help. Slight caveat:  width: size.width / 2 - 30 worked for me.

Comment: In my situation with width: size.width - 30 * 2, all the cards are visible by scrolling. :)